# Determine Daylight Savings status for different time zone in Powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime, timezone

Is there a slick way in PowerShell to ascertain if a past date in another time zone is Daylight Savings or not?  Here is the situation, our database is in Europe and the times and dates are local to that server.  Since Europe and America start and stop DST at different times, i need to take into account the hour difference for those times.
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Rather than trying to manually calculate DST days, could you use the methods in  [`[System.TimeZoneInfo]`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rslaten/2014/08/04/converting-times-from-one-time-zone-to-another-time-zone-in-powershell/) and convert to your timezone or UTC?

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/201534).  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Are you wanting to know if DST is in effect? Or are you trying to convert from a specific time zone to another? Or to/from UTC? Which specific time zone?  Is there a reason the database times aren't in UTC to begin with?

Comment: Well, the reason the database values are not UTC is because I did not write the ERP system! :)

Comment: What I'm attempting to do is produce a report of submitted tasks retrieved from a database table for a prior time frame (not current date and time) but show the data in Central time for our local people.  Since Europe is normally 7 hours ahead of us, the calculation is rather simple except for the days when we go to DST before Europe does and then when they return to standard time before we do.  So, to recap, I want to be able to accurately convert any European date/time to the local date/time.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to try to determine whether DST is in effect or not.  Just let the .NET Framework do the conversion for you.

First, decide which time zone IDs you are converting from and to.

You said your input time was in Europe, but you didn't specify exactly where.  Like the US, [Europe has multiple time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Europe).  I'll assume you meant CET/CEST (UTC+1/+2).  In Windows, you can use any of the following identifiers for this:

- `"Central Europe Standard Time"`
- `"Central European Standard Time"`
- `"Romance Standard Time"`    (why? who knows.)
- `"W. Europe Standard Time"`  (don't get fooled by the name, it's still central)

These are all the same (in Windows) except for their display names.  If you want to be precise in which one you pick, refer to [the CLDR reference](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).

For the US Central time zone, use `"Central Standard Time"`.

Then just use the [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=netframework-4.7#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId_System_DateTime_System_String_System_String_) function, as follows:

```
# collect your input (through db, or whatever mechanism you have)
$inputDateTime = Get-Date -Date "2017-06-27 00:00:00"

# pick your time zones
$fromTimeZone = "Central Europe Standard Time"  # EU
$toTimeZone = "Central Standard Time"           # USA

# convert
$outputDateTime = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
  $inputDateTime, $fromTimeZone, $toTimeZone)

# output
Write-Output $outputDateTime
```

Comment: Mr. Johnson,  Thanks for the solution.  You have opened my eyes and I will reverse my attack.  Instead of starting with CET time of <date> 7:00:00 to <date +1> 6:59:59 I will start with CST 00:00:00 to 23:50:59 and convert that.  This way, as you suggest, I won't need to fuss with the starting/ending hour.  Rick

Comment: Don't do the :59:59 thing. Instead use a half open range. In other words, >= 00:00 today and < 00:00 tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread, but I actually needed to be able to determine whether or not it's DST currently.  We have a server whose local TZ is set to UTC (which doesn't see DST) and have an automation that needs to be able to know when it's 4pm local time.  So the script is all in UTC, but I can then add an hour or not based on the value of the result of this beast:

```
$DST = ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc(
    (get-date).ToString(),
    [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time")
)).isdaylightsavingtime()
```

Answer (score 0):

Cole, I love the inspiration as your response was a needle in a haystick and just what I needed. However, it produced an error. After some messing around, I got the following to work:

```
$isDST = ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime(), [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"))).IsDaylightSavingTime()
```

*(in PowerShell v4)*